# lwjgl converting mouseLook to keys

Tags: java, lwjgl

Hey guy's I'm working on a 3D project using lwjgl. At the moment the players camera view is moved by the mouse. Movement is done using the arrow keys & i'd like to convert the mouse view to w,a,s,d so you no longer have to use the mouse.

Why am I doing this? I've got an interface system that I can't use because the application currently grabs the mouse to move the view, so the player can not interact with the interfaces.

What I've got:

```
public void cameraView() {
    if (Mouse.isGrabbed()) {
        float mouseDX = Mouse.getDX() * 0.8f * 0.16f;
        float mouseDY = Mouse.getDY() * 0.8f * 0.16f;
        if (rotation.y + mouseDX >= 360) {
            rotation.y = rotation.y + mouseDX - 360;
        } else if (rotation.y + mouseDX < 0) {
            rotation.y = 360 - rotation.y + mouseDX;
        } else {
            rotation.y += mouseDX;
        }
        if (rotation.x - mouseDY >= -89 && rotation.x - mouseDY <= 89) {
            rotation.x += -mouseDY;
        } else if (rotation.x - mouseDY < -89) {
            rotation.x = -89;
        } else if (rotation.x - mouseDY > 89) {
            rotation.x = 89;
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me out that'd be awesome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {rotation.y -= 1;}
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {rotation.y += 1;}
```

This should do the same thing as Mouse.getDX()
Alternatively, you could use:

```
while(Keyboard.next()) {
  if(Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE) {
    if(Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
      Mouse.setGrabbed(!Mouse.isGrabbed());
      Mouse.setCursorPosition(Display.getWidth()/2, Display.getHeight()/2);
}}}

if(Mouse.isGrabbed()) {
//Use mouse for moving
} else {
//Use mouse for interface
}
```